# getting expected numeric argument in the sqoop command

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

HI I am trying to sqoop the data from oracle to hadoop. This is my script.

`sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.129.1.10)(PORT = 1111))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = bbb)))" --username aaa --password bcd --query "select * from aa.table where \$CONDITIONS" -m 1  --target-dir /data/dev/rdv/tmpacct/ --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table aa --hive-drop-import-delims --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec`

error :- Expected Numeric Argument.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the connection string in this format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.129.1.10:1111:bbb
```

Please let me know if that works!